# How can I completely remove my Visual C++ Express installation?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, uninstall, visual-studio-2010, hotfix

I have a bunch of 'Hotfix for Visual C++ Standard 2010 Beta 1 - ENU' updates installed.
As well as 1 'Hotfix for Microsoft Visual C++ Express - ENU'

I have already completely uninstalled Visual C++ Express 2010 as best as I could.
But I would like to get rid of these left overs.

Problem is, there's no uninstall option for the 20 Beta 1 hotfixes, and when I try to uninstall the other one, I get a nice 'This action is only valid for products that are currently installed.'

Here's a screenshot for better reference:
[image: Here's a screenshot for better reference.]
Like I said, I don't have Visual C++ installed anymore, so I want to get rid of these.

Comment: So click on each one and it will be removed from the list.  Your only other option is to roll your system back using a restore point.

Comment: @Ramhound I can't, that's the problem. And using system restore isn't an option unfortunately.

Comment: What do you mean you can't? When I normally get that message the entry is removed from the list.  The files technically already were removed when you uninstalled Visual C++ Standard 2010 Beta 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 would be to use System Restore if you have an appropriate restore point handy.

Option 2 would be to reinstall Visual C++ Express 2010 and them uninstall everything in reverse order, i.e. hotfixes/updates first and finally the app itself.

If Options 1 and 2 are not possible for some reason, I recommend you try this instead:

1. At an *elevated* command prompt, type:

   ```
   dism /Online /Get-Packages > Packages.txt
   ```
2. Open **Packages.txt** and you'll see something similar to the following:

   ```
   Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
   Version: 6.1.7600.16385

   Image Version: 6.1.7600.16385

   Packages listing:

   Package Identity : Package_for_KB2705219~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.1
   State : Superseded
   Release Type : Security Update
   Install Time : 15-08-2012 05:38 PM

   ...

   The operation completed successfully.
   ```
3. Based on the information about each package, try and identify the ones you want to remove. For example, the one above corresponds to [this update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2705219). Similarly, try and locate the packages for the hotfixes listed in your screenshot, such as [this one](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983233) for example.
4. Now use a command similar to the following to remove the specified packages:

   ```
   dism /Online /Remove-Package /PackageName:Package_for_KB2705219~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.1 /PackageName:<Package Identity 2> /PackageName:<Package Identity 3> ...
   ```

Hopefully it will work and not throw the same error about the main program no longer being installed. If it doesn't work, a final option might be to use some freeware/commercial uninstallation utility, but not sure which one would work and how well.

---

**Edit:** Some more things to try:

1. [Visual Studio 2010 Uninstall Utility](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall)
2. From an *elevated* command prompt:

   ```
   wusa /uninstall /kb:<KB Number> (For example: wusa /uninstall /kb:983233)
   ```

Comment: Hmm what if I can't find any reference to those updates in Packages.txt?

Comment: Then try one of the other options. If nothing works as I said there are utilities such as Revo Uninstaller that *might* help, but I have no experience with them so cannot recommend anything specific.

Comment: Alright, thanks very much for your help and detailed post.

Comment: Sure, let me know if the *dism* method worked.

Comment: It didn't, I already tried.

Comment: You found no matching packages at all, or did it throw an error?

Comment: No errors, but I couldn't find any packages (I only tried 2)

Comment: See the edits above - maybe one of them will help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Windows 10 (it was upgraded from 8 and I believe 7 before that, so there's various leftover crud like this). Following the instructions from this link (at the bottom) got rid of the bottom set: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualc/gg697159

> 1. Uninstall Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1
> 2. Run the following from the command line to ensure that all related files have been removed from the system.  Note:  if you receive the error “This action is only valid for products that are currently installed."  you can safely ignore the error, because the files have already been removed.
>
>    a. On all systems, run the following from the command line:
>    msiexec /x {2F8B731A-5F2D-3EA8-8B25-C3E5E43F4BDB}
>
>    b. If on an x64 system, run this additional command from the command line:
>    msiexec /x {81455DEB-FC7E-3EE5-85CA-2EBDD9FD61EB}
>
>    c. If on an IA64 system, run this additional command from the command line:
>    msiexec /x {AC917391-EEBA-3240-81FF-1E9EC0D49403}

I was able to remove the top one (KB2542054) by opening regedit and deleting the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{46F8CF66-AB83-38A7-99B2-A5BE507EE472}.KB2542054` key. Since it also said "This action is only valid for products that are currently installed" for me when I tried to uninstall it, I think doing this is probably safe (I backed up the key just in case).

Answer (score -2):

CC Cleaner is a great program found here: http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download
It should allow you to individually install thous programs in a safe and clean manor. It can also search for unused File extensions, missing Dlls, and other parts of junk that is often left over from programs like that. It is free to use and would be the best solution for quickly and safely removing all the old packages left over.

Comment: CCleaner doesn't list Windows updates or hotfixes for uninstallation, only apps. Also, it might be able to clean up the registry and remove the (orphan) entries, but I'm pretty sure it'll leave the actual hotfix files behind.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion CCeaner will not list hotfixes unless its windows xp. However you can still tell CCleaner to manually access the hotfixes using the include feature in CCleaner. That way it will detect the hotfixes.

Comment: I suppose you mean Options / Include? When I click the Add button all I see is [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8YUHZ.png). How would you select hotfixes from this dialog?